# Im trying to check if its a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

So I started by creating a base case. Then came up with this:

```
list([]).
list([_|_]):-
    list([_],true),
    list([_|_],true).
```

So when I run it its supposed to do this

```
-list([1,2,3]) → True.

-list(hello) → False.
```

Comment: but I'm stuck. any help would be great

Comment: Prolog has a predicate `is_list/1` that checks if a variable is a list.

Comment: ya is there a way to do it without using is_list

Comment: You need to think this through before just writing code. `[|]` is not valid list format. What does that mean? And why do you sometimes have a second argument to your `list` predicate? That doesn't make sense. What  does a list look like? It can be an empty list `[]`, or not (it is a list with a head and a tail - `[_|_]`). All lists have one of those two forms.

Comment: im 3 hours new to prolog. okay ill look into it

Comment: Even if you're 3 minutes new to Prolog, you don't write code by guessing. It's not very productive. Experimenting with valid syntax, yes, but not guessing. You need to study and read examples and instructional material.

Comment: list(L):-
list([]).

list(L):-
list([_|_]).

Comment: shouldn't this work?

Comment: i put the underscore but it got deleted in stack overflow

Comment: list(L):-
list([]).

list(L):-
list([_|_]).

Comment: No, that's not meaningful and it's not how Prolog works. `list(L) :- list([]).` says *`L` is a list if the empty list is a list*, which certainly is not true. If you want to say that `[]` is a list, you simply assert `list([])`. Then a query of `list([]).` will succeed, and `list(L)` will yield `L = []`. Do you have a Prolog text book, or have you gone through  any online tutorials?

Comment: You need to read the  online help for formatting in Stackoverflow.com. If you format as code, the underscore won't be deleted.

Comment: so i got it to result true if its an empty list but once i put values in the list it says false.

Comment: I've given you all the information you need to define a valid list. Read my 2nd comment. If you're not sure how to express that in Prolog, then see my 4th comment. I'm not going to do all of your work and thinking for you. ;)

Comment: maybe i just dont get the syntax. I've been googling and trying to grasp it but still confused.

Comment: can you just write it then explain it lol! it would help me out a lot. I'm a visual learner.

Comment: I'll give you an example. Prolog is about rules (facts and predicates). If you say, `list([]).` that's a rule that says *`[]` is a list*. If I wrote `list(a)` that would say, *`a` is a list* (which of course isn't true, so I wouldn't say that). But what would you say to define a list?

Comment: Look up "Learn Prolog Now" and follow that tutorial to try to understand basic Prolog a little better. This isn't really a tutorial site.

Comment: ok i finally figured it out! thanks for your help

Comment: Yay! Glad you figured it out!